# How to copy a list data into the TextField with Single-line

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

How I can copy a list value below into TextField with Single-line?

```
A20230101001
A20230101002
A20230101003
A20230101004
```

The issue is when I copy this list into TextField then it just only the value A20230101001 displayed

Thanks,

Comment: What if you set the value of `Functional.Multi-Line` property to `Yes` ?

Comment: I also want to use the trigger KEY-ENTER to go to the next item in the Forms. So if I use Functional.Multi-Line then triggers KEY-ENTER not working. 

Or you can help me with how I can use trigger KEY-ENTER in Functional.Multi-Line

Comment: Current I don't have Forms installed to reproduce, but I know that there was a trigger called `KEY-NEXT-ITEM`, instead, which contains `next_item` or `next_field` command.

Comment: KEY-NEXT-ITEM is used in the TAB key, not ENTER.

Comment: No valid for both keys(but I don't know whether firing of it prevented for the multi-line case that you might test)

Comment: I tried KEY-NEXT-ITEM but it's just working only with TAB key

Answer (score 0):

> How I can copy a list value below into TextField **with Single-line**?

By replacing CRLF with something else, e.g. a space character. For example (this is SQL*Plus, column contents is contained in a table column - in Forms, that would be a field).

```
SQL> select * From test;

COL
---------------------------------------------------
A20230101001
A20230101002
A20230101003
A20230101004
```

Dump function shows which character(s) are used for *new line*:

```
SQL> select dump(col) From test;
 
DUMP(COL)
------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=51: 65,50,48,50,51,48,49,48,49,48,48,49,10,65,50,48,...
               A  2  0  2  3  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  --
                                                   ^
                                                   |
                                                   here it is
```

Therefore, replace `CHR(10)` with a space:

```
SQL> select replace(col, chr(10), ' ') result
  2  from test;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------
A20230101001 A20230101002 A20230101003 A20230101004
```

If `dump` showed that it is CRLF (carriage return/linefeed), represented by both `CHR(10)` and `CHR(13)`, you'd use nested `replace`s:

```
SQL> select replace(replace(col, chr(13)), chr(10), ' ') result
  2  from test;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------
A20230101001 A20230101002 A20230101003 A20230101004

SQL>
```

---

In Forms, pick any trigger that suits your needs and

```
:block.some_field := replace(:block.some_field, chr(10), ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, Imagine I have 1 text field in the Forms, I need to copy the list value above into the text field in the forms, it's regarding UI, not a table to parse the value

Comment: Principle is just the same, no difference. Work with field value instead of column value. See edited answer.

Comment: The problem here is that the Text-Field Single-Line does not receive enough input, so if there is not enough input, the replacement is meaningless. As my question in this post. I input a list value A20230101001
A20230101002
A20230101003
A20230101004 but Textfield Single-Line shows only A20230101001

Answer (score 0):

Trigger KEY-ENTER is forms action trigger like any other (KEY-ENTQRY, KEY-EXIT, KEY-COMMIT....) - it is not connected to any kind of keystroke listener as you are trying to use it.
So, it looks like you are asking for event trigger that doesn't exist. It would be nice to have the oportunity to use WHEN-KEY-PRESSED trigger in forms. Unfortunately there is no such trigger.
There is a way (using Java Bean) that allows sending back to the Forms application each key pressed in any Text Item. Never tryed it myself, but it is described at: http://forms-pjc-bean.over-blog.com/article-15980196.html - maybe there you could find the solution to do what you need.